# NSRangeException randomly crash app in object at index

Tags: crash

NSDictionary *latestCollection=[json objectWithString:responseString  error:&error];

```
NSDictionary *data=[latestCollection valueForKey:@"results"];
if([data count]>0 && data!=nil)
{
    arrayAddress=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[data valueForKey:@"formatted_address"]];
    /*********Showing address of new location******/
    [lblAddress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0]]];
    [lblPickUpAddress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0]]];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Address not available");
}
```

Comment: NSDictionary *latestCollection=[json objectWithString:responseString  error:&error];
    NSDictionary *data=[latestCollection valueForKey:@"results"];
    if([data count]>0 && data!=nil)
    {
        arrayAddress=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[data valueForKey:@"formatted_address"]];
        /*********Showing address of new location******/
        [lblAddress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0]]];
        [lblPickUpAddress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0]]];
    }

Comment: Ive answered your question, but i wont answer any of your questions that you post and do not even tell us WHERE is crashes or what you have tried. You have a debugger that could simply have been telling you what the problem is!

Comment: iam getting the crash like dis .it is a random crash

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is your if clause:

```
if([data count]>0 && data!=nil)
```

`if` will evaluate from left to right, so first, it accesses `data` for the `count`, but it may be `nil`, so simply switch the expressions like so:

```
if( data!=nil && [data count]>0)
```

the `if` clause will stop, as soon as one of the expressions if `false`, so it will do a check for `nil`, if its NOT `nil`, then it will access data to get the count. If `data` is `nil`, then the `data` will not be accessed. Thats why your app crashes.